# How to copy folders containing classes to another project - swift

Tags: swift

I want to move folders from one project in swift to another project.
When I drag folders into the new project, it won't recognise many classes.

It works only when I create the classes one by one in new project and move its content one by one from old project.

And when i move the folder to new project, its colour becames blue and not yellow.

Any advise what I have to do in order to make everything works just by drawing the folders?

Comment: Bro first just create a "New Group" and then rename this Group, right click on it and tap "Show in Finder" and paste all files there.
Again right click on that Group and tap on "Add files to". Simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "drag and drop", you mean in the project's files or in XCode in the file panel?

If you drop just on the projects folders, just follow aBilal17's comment above.

If you add your file in your project, right in XCode, make sure they are also in the target they're supposed to be (the check mark in the inspector on the Identity and Type panel, under "Target Membership").

Comment: Thanks man, previously I didn't notice to check mark what ever under Membership. However, I checked all folders, but still it is giving me errors